# What does shomo-a tishm'u in the shema prayer mean?

Tags: hebrew, translation, shema, ekev

The second paragraph of the shema begins with "and it will come to pass that if you continually hearken to my commandments..."

Apparently shomo-a tishm'u means continually hearken but I would like to know specifically what each of those words means. They both have the same shin mem ayin stem in them, the second one just has a tav thrown on the beginning and a vav tossed on to the end, so they should mean something very similar. Thanks.

Comment: Hebrew uses a repetition of a verb for emphasis or to mean surely or continually. Thus the literal English is "hear you will hear"

Comment: More like "hearing you will hear".

Answer (score 1):

The first word is the [infinitive](/q/2329) and the second word is the future (second-person plural) of the same verb, to listen/hear.

Comment: More specifically, the infinitive absolute and the imperfect.